# Is it possible to get the invoking class instance in a JFrame in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In a Java Swing application I have a JFrame which invokes other JFrames.
Specifically I am dealing with a JFrame to select UI colors.

Each color button instantiates a new JFrame which has just a JColorChooser and OK/Cancel buttons.

Once the color is selected I need to return the chosed color back to the original JFrame which invoked the JFrame with the JColorChooser.

So far I have been doing by explicitly assigning an attribute in the JFrame which contains the JColorChooser.

```java
public class PropertiesColor extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MainWindow mainWindow;

    public PropertiesColor(MainWindow mw) {
        initComponents();
        mainWindow = mw;
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        jColorChooser = new javax.swing.JColorChooser();
        ...
    }
```

MainWindow object has attributes/methods to use the selected color from JColorChooser, hence once you close the JFrame with the JColorChooser you just do:

```
 mainWindow.setBackgroundColor(jColorChooser.getColor());
```

A question I have about this pattern is: is it possible to determine  `mainWindow` without explicitly assigning it when `PropertiesColor` is created? Sort kind of `.getInvokingJFrame` method

Comment: The canonical solution is for the sub-windows to be dialog windows, in Swing, JDialogs. Make them modal if you want the GUI to be on hold until the user makes a selection. Also the sub-windows should ***not*** be changing the state of the main GUI directly, that's a bad design. Instead, the main window should change its own state based on the choices made in the sub-window. This makes your question itself somewhat moot.

Comment: But how can I get the result from the subwindow?

Comment: [See common similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+get+data+from+another+jframe+site:stackoverflow.com), many answered by me -- but again, use JDialogs. The difficulty is almost always not *how* to get information, just query the state of the dialog's model. Rather the difficulty is *when*, and if a modal dialog this is easily solved since code flow is frozen until the dialog has been dealt with. Else you must respond to an event.

Comment: Thanks I will use JDialogs and check the link you provide.